# Ganeti master IP and cluster name

Tags: networking, ganeti

I'm trying to set up a ganeti cluster.

My problem is that I don't understand the role of the "cluster name" and the associated "master IP".

The installation requirement is that every node and future instance must have a resolvable host name, and the cluster name must be resolvable too.

What IP address should I assign to the cluster name? What it'll be used for?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The cluster IP is an independent IP address that's on the same network as the nodes.

The cluster name is a fully qualified, independent DNS record that resolves to this IP, either using /etc/hosts file or a standard lookup.

This IP address will jump around, on a virtual interface like eth0:0, depending on which node is the current master. The other node(s) will use the master's name to communicate with it.

All nodes must be able to resolve the master's name at all times, or else cluster management will be severely compromised. (I don't thinks VMs will actually crash)